# Form submitted without button clicked

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

This is my first post.

I've been working on a Chrome Extension and yesterday I came across this problem. I already solved it, I just don't quite understand why it works this way. So if anyone can explain it, thank you!

So, in my popup.html I have a form with a submit button (and in popup.js some checkboxes may be generated dinamically inside this form):

```
    <div>
        <form id="confirmation">
            <div id="ing"></div>
            <div id="meth"></div>
            <button id="check" type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Inside the script, I have this code, and it works fine so far:

```
let form = document.getElementById("confirmation");
form.onsubmit = () => {window.alert("submited")};
```

The problem was that before I had this, which triggered the Alert when I clicked the extension Icon, without the form being submitted:

```
let form = document.getElementById("confirmation");
form.addEventListener("submit", window.alert("submited"));
```

Why does it behave like that?

I'm fairly new to programming.

Cheers from Portugal!

Comment: In the second code snippet, you are explicitly calling `alert` before passing its return value (`undefined`) to the `addEventListener` method. In the first one, you are passing it a function as you should

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats because the second parameter is a callback and you are simply calling the function.

This passes the return value of  `window.alert("submited")` as the second parameter

```
form.addEventListener("submit", window.alert("submited"));
```

This would pass a function that when called will trigger the `window.alert`

```
form.addEventListener("submit", () => { window.alert("submited") });
```

Comment: Thank you!

This means that in the Alert in the first one is triggered along with the Listener?

Comment: Its triggered when you are adding the event listener instead of when the event is triggered